# Java NullPointerException on Simple Array for Chinese Studies

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, nullpointerexception

I am working on a very simple command line program in Java to test my knowledge of the Chinese writing system. The goal is to present English, Pinyin, or Hanzi and to then force the user to enter the 2 which are not shown. After working through a few simple Array errors, I encountered a NullPointerException.

Now, I understand what it is, I simply can't see why it is occurring.

In the file called Master.java, I have the following:

```
static final String [] [] Mandarray = {{"You", "Nǐ", "你"}, {"Good", "Hǎo", "好"}};
```

In the constructor of my Chinese_Mandarin object, I copy the contents of this array to a new one, one of the members of the Chinese_Mandarin object, like so,

```
    public Chinese_Mandarin(char transfer){ 
    if(transfer == 'n' || transfer != 'y')System.exit(0);

    for (int i = (Master.Mandarray.length-1); i>0 ;i--){
        mandalist [i][0] = Master.Mandarray[i][0];
        mandalist [i][1] = Master.Mandarray[i][1];
        mandalist [i][2] = Master.Mandarray[i][2];
    }
```

With the above 'if' part of the system that asks if the user wishes to continue, it is not important.
Next, I check to make sure that the same entry isn't to be shown again by seeing if the first character is *, which, by my program, indicates the entry has already been used.

```
public void presenter(){
    Scanner chinEngl = new Scanner(System.in);
    restart: for (int i = mandalist.length; i>0 ;i--){
        randInt = random.nextInt(mandalist.length);
        randIntSub = random.nextInt(3);
        if(mandalist[randInt][randIntSub] == ""){
            continue restart;
        }
        else if (((mandalist[randInt][randIntSub]).charAt(0)) == '*'){
            continue restart;
        }
```

Here, I initialize a scanner to be used later, create two random integers to be used later on, and make sure the elements aren't empty (for if they are, I pass to the tag 'restart' to continue looping despite this).

On the line:

```
else if (((mandalist[randInt][randIntSub]).charAt(0)) == '*'){
```

I receive a NullPointerException error, but cannot fathom why... The Master.mandarray has been transferred to mandalist, I can assume (but that's why I am here) and as such there should be no trouble retrieving the first char of a full entry, right?

Is the problem that the system may retrieve a Chinese character and not know how to handle it?
Or is something that I am missing afoot?
Thank you to anyone who may help me. You will surely get credits!

Comment: Your use of continue labels is redundant and rather bad practice.

Comment: How about making an intance of your Master class an make use of setters and getters of your mandarray.    Don't make them static of course.   The pass the master.getmanarray to your cons?

Comment: Oh yeah I think it would be better using an instance of master class than doing a static call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of bugs.

#### Bug 1:

Use `equals()` not `==` to compare strings. This line:

```
if(mandalist[randInt][randIntSub] == ""){
```

should be:

```
if(mandalist[randInt][randIntSub].equals("")){
```

or better:

```
if(mandalist[randInt][randIntSub].isEmpty()){
```

#### Bug 2:

java arrays are zero-based; the highest index of an array is `length - 1`, not `length`, and the lowest is zero, not one, so your loop:

```
for (int i = mandalist.length; i>0 ;i--){
```

should be:

```
for (int i = mandalist.length - 1; i >= 0 ;i--){
```

#### Bug 3 (the one causing your problem):

similar to Bug 2, your loop stops short of initialising the element at index zero, so it should be:

```
for (int i = (Master.Mandarray.length-1); i >= 0 ;i--){ // i >= 0, not i > 0
```

---

Unless you really need to loop down the indexes, use the industry standard approach of going up the indexes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Master.Mandarray.length-1; i++){
```

Comment: Thank you. I perpetually forget the .equals() issue involving references as String is not a primitive right? As for the length-1, I could have sworn I changed that earlier, but it must have been for another loop, and forgotten for this one. This community is wonderful!

Comment: No worries. I think you question has been answered now - you should probably accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line

```
for (int i = (Master.Mandarray.length-1); i>0 ;i--){
```

The test `i>0` is done before the loop body, so the loop is not done when `i` is zero.

This means that the remaining elements of the array are `null`.

IMHO it is more common to use the old C-style idiom

```
for (int i = 0; i < Master.Mandarray.length; i++) {
```

for looping through arrays, unless there is a special reason for going backwards.

Comment: I was wondering why the use of i-- seemed so foreign! This will really help me and I do appreciate it. Sorry to violate the comment guidelines but I have to express my gratitude.